# Install LAMP on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, lamp

I want to install lamp with very minimal steps.I have followed this tutorial

https://www.cloudjojo.com/how-to-install-lamp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04/

Is there any easy way than these steps.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any easy way than these steps.

yes, you could ask someone else to do it for you.

Seriously though, most LAMP installations are darn insecure. Only use them when you want to test something on your own computer. If you want to go to production (or connect it to the Internet) make sure you install separate components and keep them up to date. That means:

- Up to data OS (BSD or Linux or windows or ...)
- Up to date HTTP server, e.g. httpd or ngix
- Up to data database server (E.g. postgress or mysql)
- Up to data PHP (and do check this, there are frequent PHP updates).

All of this makes it **less easy** to install and maintain.

You will also need to learn about access rights and how to set them properly (e.g. a `www` user with no rights on any part of the filesystem bar the www files. Proper understanding of permissions. (e.g. learning that anything with chmod -R 777 in it is dead wrong).

---

Having said all that, lets get to your actual question:

I did read the instructions in your link (which BTW could die any day, please do include all relevant information in your post). It seems a very simple recipe for setting up a LAMP stack onder Ubuntu. It is almost impossible to make it any more trivial.